# Stop unauthorised servlet access

Tags: java, servlets

I have created a basic servlet to handle logins on my web app.

currently its in the form;

index.jsp -> loginServlet -> admin.jsp

Requests are sent over the mapping /login

the problem i have is if you try and access the /login without sending post/get it gives a NullPointerException.

How can you handle request sent directly? or is there a better way to handle this?

Stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    loginServlet.doGet(loginServlet.java:39)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:689)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
```

---

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws IOException, ServletException
{
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
    String task = request.getParameter("task");
    if(task.equals("logout")) {
        session.removeAttribute("username");
    } 
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp");
    dispatcher.forward(request, response);
}
```

Comment: You'll have to give us more to go on, some code (implementation of doGet())and a stack trace at least.

Comment: You could consider fixing your servlet to not throw a null-pointer exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *if you try and access the /login without sending post/get*

How is that ever possible?

I guess there's some misconception or bad design going on. Here are some hints to put you on the right track:

1. Put `login.jsp` in `/WEB-INF` folder.
2. Rewrite `doGet()` so that it forwards to that JSP.
3. Keep the login handling job in `doPost()`. Make sure that it never throws an `RuntimeException`. Those kind of exceptions are basically developer's faults. Always check user input on `null` and never trust user input.

This way the login page will be opened when you call that servlet by a GET request (e.g. directly entering its URL in address bar, following a bookmark, etc and the login handling job will be done when you submit a `<form method="post">` inside that JSP.

As a bonus, you get nicer URLs.

#### See also:

- [Our servlets tag wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info)

Comment: im guessing its because i tried to handle the logout using doGet, i have removed this and added forwarder and it fixed my problem, is it better to create a new servlet for logging out?

Comment: Yes. Just let it basically do `request.getSession().invalidate(); response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath());` in `doGet()`.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are your NullPointer exception is being caused by this:

```
String task = request.getParameter("task");
if(task.equals("logout")) {
    session.removeAttribute("username");
}
```

because you are not first checking to ensure you even retrieved a **task** parameter.  Need to check for null on that value.